# Null as well as not Null Values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null

I want to get information of teacher, by comparing the `u.fld_id = ct.fld_teacher_id`
and if ct.fld_teacher_id is null I will show not assigned yet. But row with null ct.fld_teacher_id does not show up at execution.

Here is my query.

```
  SELECT ct.fld_id as id, ct.fld_serial, ct.fld_city, ct.fld_venue_name, 
        ct.fld_start_time, ct.fld_end_time, 
        ct.fld_duration, ct.fld_available_seats, 
        ct.fld_course_price, ct.fld_status,
        c.fld_name, u.fld_first_name, u.fld_last_name,
        ct.fld_status, ct.fld_teacher_id, ct.fld_training_name,
        ct.fld_class, ct.fld_level, ct.fld_is_fixed, tt.fld_name as training_type_name
   FROM tbl_course_training as ct, tbl_users as u,
        tbl_courses as c, tbl_training_types as tt
   WHERE c.fld_id = ct.fld_course_id AND u.fld_id = ct.fld_teacher_id AND 
       ct.fld_teacher_id = 'NULL' AND tt.fld_id = ct.fld_training_type_id
```

Comment: can you show us some sample data .

Answer (score 0):

I can't sort out your query without knowing the structure. However there are few things I have noticed.

- You cannot compare null values as `ct.fld_teacher_id = 'NULL'` (*null
  is not a string*)

  ```
  ct.fld_teacher_id is null -- Correct way
  ```
- If you need to select even when `ct.fld_teacher_id is null` then

  ```
  u.fld_id = isnull(ct.fld_teacher_id, u.fld_id) --or (sql-server) 
  u.fld_id = ct.fld_teacher_id or ct.fld_teacher_id is null --(my sql or sql-server)
  u.fld_id = COALESCE(ct.fld_teacher_id, u.fld_id)  --(my sql)
  ```
- Also avoid old method of joining tables like `From Table1 t1, Table2
  t2`

  ```
  From Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 On t1.Key = t2.Key --Correct way
  ```
- I think you need to have a few `Left Join`s here. Please [check this
  link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/) to understand how Sql Joins work

Comment: I get teacher detail (name, email, etc) by comparing u.fld = ct.fld_teacher_id, who is teaching the course.
Say a course is registered but teacher is not yet assigned.
Value in fld_teacher_id will be null.

Comment: @user1863272: You need a `left join` in that case. Read the above link to understand joins.